# how to integrate google docs in web application (preview, edit, save)

Tags: angular, google-docs, google-docs-api, office365api, google-document-viewer

I want to integrate **google docs** in web application (Angular 10) for **preview, edit and save**.

I have documents stored on my server. I want to preview documents using google docs which stored on my server(it can be stored on Amazon S3 or Azure etc).

I want to edit that document using google docs and save back to my server(user is logged in with google credentials with all permission).

> I am aware of this :
> [https://docs.google.com/a/[DOMINIO]/viewer?url=[FILE_URL]](https://docs.google.com/a/%5BDOMINIO%5D/viewer?url=%5BFILE_URL%5D) , but it is
> used for preview with 25 MB file size limitation.

Basically I need to integrate google docs for preview, edit and save documents in my web application.

Same functionality I want to achieve with Microsoft Office 365(with subscription).

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*The* ***only*** *way this is possible is by using a third-party storage system.*

#### More Information:

As per the help article on [Edit Drive files on 3rd-party storage systems](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9164215?hl=en):

> As an administrator, you can let users in your organization edit Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides (Google files) stored on third-party storage systems.

and:

> To enable editing and collaboration, Google caches files stored on third-party servers for 30 days. While files are being cached, their content is subject to Google’s terms. Google files stored on third-party servers are subject to the terms of the third party.
>
> In addition, Google files stored on third-party servers can be managed, controlled, removed, and exported only through the third-party provider's controls. Google Drive file-management controls, including access control, data location commitments, data loss prevention (DLP), vault retention policies, and Drive API access are not available to Google files stored on third-party servers.

#### Things to note:

- If your organization has a paid account with the storage provider, each user must be signed in with a Google Workspace account.
- The email addresses associated with a user's storage provider account and Google Workspace account must match. To ensure that addresses match, add the email addresses associated with your users' storage provider accounts as email aliases of their Google Workspace accounts.

You can read more information about this on the above link.

#### Related Questions:

- [Edit files with Google Docs but store them locally in home folder - Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27052)

#### References:

- [Edit Drive files on 3rd-party storage systems - Google Workspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9164215?hl=en)

Comment: You have explained about Box integration with google docs. What if my files stored on my own server or Amazon S3...??

Comment: @chirag It's not possible, the only way is using a third party storage system. Google Docs files are native to the Drive environment and you can't edit files stored on your own server using the Docs editor.